# How to use SPI from kernel space?

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver, space, kernel-module, spi

I need to use SPI in my kernel module.

It looks straight forward to call *spi_** functions directly, e.g.:

```
....
#include <linux/spi/spi.h>
....
struct spi_device  *spi;
struct spi_message msg;
....
spi_message_add_tail(&xfer, &msg);
spi_sync(spi, &msg);
....
```

However, how to fill up the *spi_device* structure (e.g. defined [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.91/source/include/linux/spi/spi.h#L142))?

In other words, how to refer a particular SPI device?

Thanks for directions!

Comment: Not a recommended method but you can open the spi dev from devfs in kernel space

Comment: Yes, thanks, that works already, but I hate switching between kernel space and user space.
The funny thing is I see that some other drivers use _spi*_ functions, but I still cannot understand how they pass the info.

Comment: I tried to look up but I am unable to find another way, Can you point me to drivers that use those spi functions ?

Comment: Not exactly I understand what kind of devices you are talking about. Which of them is master and which is slave? In case you are doing a driver for the slave device, the  enumeration happens based on ACPI or Device Tree. There tables defines what slaves are connected to which masters (host controllers on board).

Comment: @yashC , you can find many references, if you run in the kernel tree:


    `find drivers/ -name "*.c" -exec grep -l spi_message_add_tail {} \;`

Comment: @0andriy , I have two master devices, e.g. `/dev/spidev0.0` and would like to use them from a kernel module. I don't like the idea to switch to user mode when I need them.

Comment: @SergeyManucharian, provide a correct ACPI or Device Tree table for that. That's how it's connected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711842/add-spi-slave-device-in-linux-4-9-device-tree-for-raspbery-pi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does kernel code knows which spi bus is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070439/how-does-kernel-code-knows-which-spi-bus-is-using)

Comment: @0andriy, I don't understand how those questions (links) are related to mine?
I do have my DeviceTree, I do have the corresponding device nodes in /dev, everything perfectly works at the SPI side. I use those devices from user space.
Now I want to send a SPI message from within a different kernel module (instead of a user program). So, how can I refer a particular master device to send that message from? I thought, there must be a way to do everything in kernel space.

Comment: You should **not** use them from user space. Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634892/linux-spidev-why-it-shouldnt-be-directly-in-devicetree/ Perhaps you need to update your question to show what kind of device tree excerpt you have, etc.

Comment: «You should not use them from user space»։ /dev/spidev0.1 etc **are** to be used from **user** space. My question is how to use them from **kernel** space.
I work with BeagleBone Black, the device tree's fragments are here for 2 SPI devices: [SPI0](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/bb.org-overlays/blob/master/src/arm/BB-SPIDEV0-00A0.dts) and [SPI1](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/bb.org-overlays/blob/master/src/arm/BB-SPIDEV1-00A0.dts).

Comment: The point is, you should never use `/dev/spidev*` at all. The example you shown is for providing them to **user** space for debugging (initial playing with) the device.

Comment: Have you already find the answer? I have a similar issue and looking for a proper way to use SPI driver from inside of my custom driver.

Comment: No, I haven't. I switch to user space and then back:
            old_fs = get_fs();
            set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
            ....
            set_fs(old_fs);
(I'm not sure how to write code in a comment)